# Python class method not recognizing input

Tags: python

I've created a class called `neuron_network` that references another class called `neuron` in its `__init__` method. It uses a method I have defined in the neuron called `add_inputs`, which takes a numerical input `i`. However when I try to call the `__init__` method it says that the input `i` is not being given.

```
class dendrite:...

class neuron:

    def __init__(self, threshold):
            self.inputs = []

    def add_inputs(self, i):
            self.inputs += [dendrite(0.3)]*i

class neuron_network:

     def __init__(self, layers):
         self.layers = []
         for x in layers:
             self.layers += [[neuron]*x]
         for i in range(1, len(self.layers)):
             for x in self.layers[i]:
                 x.add_inputs(layers[i-1])

new = neuron_network([3,4,5])
```

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    TypeError: add_inputs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.layers += [[neuron]*x]` adds a list of `x` neuron classes to `self.layers` list.  The class not an instance.  When you call `add_inputs` you have no self, so your `i` looks like a self reference and you are missing your `i`.  Also where should the `threshold` for each neuron coming from?

```
 def __init__(self, layers):
     self.layers = [[neuron(threshold) for _ in range(x)] for x in layers]
     for prev_neurons, layer in zip(layers, self.layers[1:]):
         for n in layer:
             n.add_inputs(prev_neurons)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the neuron class into the layers, not an instance of neuron. You need `self.layers += [[neuron()]*x]`

Comment: Additionally, the unused `threshold` argument will need to be removed from the `neuron` constructor (or a value will need to be passed).

Answer (score 0):

The line `self.layers += [[neuron]*x]` should be something like `self.layers += [neuron(x)]`.  The `x` isn't a `neuron` instance, so you can't call `add_inputs` on it.  (At least, that's how it looks to me.)

You did something similar in `add_inputs` to add new dendrites into the input list.

**Edit:** To answer your question, when you reach `neuron_network.__init__`, `layers` is what you gave it: `[3,4,5]`.  Therefore, `for x in layers` sets `x` to integers 3, 4, 5 successively.

I thought from your code that 3, 4, 5 were the thresholds, since `neuron.__init__` takes a mandatory threshold parameter.  Per your comment, they are a size, so, after @tryexceptpass, try `[neuron(0.1)]*x`, replacing `0.1` with the `threshold`.

Comment: Perhaps I should have included an explanation before. The self.layers += [[neuron]*x] is me trying to add a 2D list of neurons, whereas your solution would lead to a 1D list of neurons with the values in layers being used by the neuron's init function. Ty for the answer though, why would x not be a neuron?